# Materialize tooltip only works outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am having issues manipulating this html element:

```
<a id="q" class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am a tooltip">Hover me!</a>
```

using this JavaScript code:

```
$('#q').attr('data-tooltip', 'new data');
```

Please look at the following scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

```
< script >

 function A() {
 // Do function A stuff
 }

function B() {
 // Do function B stuff
 $('#q').attr('data-position', 'right'); // THIS WORKS
 $('#q').attr('data-tooltip', 'new data'); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
}

function C() {

 // Do function C stuff
} < /script>
```

**Scenario 2**

```
< script >
$('#q').attr('data-tooltip', 'new data'); // THIS WORKS

 function A() {
 // Do function A stuff
 }

function B() {
 // Do function B stuff
 $('#q').attr('data-position', 'right'); // THIS WORKS

}

function C() {

 // Do function C stuff
} < /script>
```

Why is it that the code **$('#q').attr('data-tooltip', 'new data');** only works outside a function? My goal is to get the code to work within function B. Why is it that one code works but the other doesn't? As seen in scenario. 1. I want to dynamically change the text within the tooltip when function B runs.

Comment: what do you mean that it works? And when is function B invoked?

Comment: @codemax When the function is called. When a button is clicked.

Comment: What are you trying to even do? You seem to be using materialize wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's happening is that your code outside of your function call runs immediately. So it runs on your tooltips changing the data attribute BEFORE materialize even has a chance to set it as a tooltip.

You will need to change the content like you are doing, then re-initialize tooltip() to get the updates.

For explanation of **Scenario 1**:
Your `data-position` code works in that situation because materialize handles that attribute differently than actual content inside of the tooltip.

From what I recall, materialize actually sets the content, and it doesn't allow for changing of the content without re-initialization of the tooltip.

The position of the tooltip is initialized at the event of `mouseover` so your code would update the position just fine and then materialize would recognize this update on the `mouseover` event.

Comment: My goal is to get the code to work within the function. Why is it that one code works but the other doesn't? As seen in scenario. 1. I want to dynamically change the text within the tooltip when function B runs.

Comment: Ok .. I think my answer should cover what you're looking for. That is the reason. I'll update it and even elaborate more.